# For a convex function $f$, is the following set convex: $X := \{x ∶ -f(x) \leq 1 \}$?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, smooth-functions

> For a convex function $f$, is the following set convex: $X := \{x ∶ -f(x) \leq 1 \}$?

I know that the set $X := \{x ∶ f(x) \leq 1\}$ is convex, but I'm unsure about the $-f(x)$ in the first set.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily. Consider $f(x) = x^2 - 2$. This set would be $\{x : 2 - x^2 \leq 1\}$, i.e. $\{x : x^2 \geq 1 \}.$ But this set is not convex; for example, $-1$ and $1$ are both in the set, yet $\frac{1}{2} (-1) + \frac{1}{2} (1) = 0$ is not.

Comment: can you please provide a proof for $f$ being convex. I am unable to prove that $f(ax+(1-a)y)\le a f(x)+(1-a)f(y)$ according as Wiki.

Comment: You should be able to prove that $x^2$ is convex. Translating a function will not change this. Alternatively, you can use the alternative definition: $f(x)$ is twice-differentiable and its second derivative is always positive, so $f(x)$ is convex.

Comment: Oh! yes, thanks for the tip. I forgot the second definition.

Comment: Twice differentiability is a criterion, not a definition.  There are non differentiable convex functions.

Comment: Right; if I'm being precise, I should specify that, if $f$ is twice-differentiable, then the second derivative being positive is equivalent to being convex. Since this holds here, this suffices as proof.